# Double Quote font causing errors

Tags: javascript, double-quotes

I'm having trouble writing code because apparently some text editors and code editors and tools and developer tools use different quotes.

I've found ” causes error in javascript vs "

Look closely. The double quotes are different from each other.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I didn't post any actual code but I did post two different pairs of quotes (in my post).

Comment: You should provide a clear description of your problem, either it is in your code, or in your code editor, with screen captures maybe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, those are different characters. Here you can see the character codes

```
'”'.charCodeAt(0); // -> returns 8221
'"'.charCodeAt(0); // -> returns 34
```

You can try both of these in Chrome by typing those into the console and seeing the result.

The first, incorrect double-quote [`”`](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8221) may have been generated by something like Microsoft Word which tries to use fancier quotation marks, but it will not work in Javascript. You should use the normal quotes on your keyboard: [`"`](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/34)